# Is it necessary to put the PDO in IF statement?

Tags: php, pdo

According to how to wiki: This is how to prevent sql injection in PHP.

I just wanna ask if is it really necessary to start it with if statement?

```
$name = $_GET['username'];

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT password FROM tbl_users WHERE name=?")) {

    // Bind a variable to the parameter as a string. 
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $name);

    // Execute the statement.
    $stmt->execute();

    // Get the variables from the query.
    $stmt->bind_result($pass);

    // Fetch the data.
    $stmt->fetch();

    // Display the data.
    printf("Password for user %s is %s\n", $name, $pass);

    // Close the prepared statement.
    $stmt->close();

}
```

Comment: That's to detect if the query was prepared successfully. Although personally I use Exception Mode and let it throw instead. Leads to much less nested code (because when a query fails to prepare, that's a pretty fatal error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL injection will be impossible if you are using prepared statements, whether you wrap the function call in an if statement or not.

According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), `mysqli::prepare` returns `false`, if an error occurs during execution. The `if` statement is there to detect this, if the return value is `false`, it does not attempt to carry on with executing the query and using its result (as it would fail or lead to incorrect results).

By the way, [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) is an alternative to the `mysqli` family, and does not make an appearence in your question (so the title is a bit misleading).